# mobile drag when overflow = hidden - jquery

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, drag

I have an unordered list which is set to `overflow: hidden`. The width and height are fixed, and I want to be abble to scrol-drag the `li`'s vertically on mobile devices.

Is that possible? Or do I have to create a `div` and use it as a mask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the `<ul>` to `overflow:hidden`. Why don't you set it to `overflow:scroll`?

I have created a basic example with a bunch of list items in an unordered list that you can find here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/sbhomra/HMTpa/4/show/light/

I added a `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch` style which I believe is part of the iOS5 webkit.

I have tested this on an iPad and the scrolling works. But I haven't tested it on other touch devices.

## Edit

I actually found something called iScroll that could help you simulate scrolling across mobile devices: http://cubiq.org/iscroll

Comment: `overflow:scroll` gives me those terrible scrollbars. But that iScroll seems to be just what I need.